# Serialize ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I have this crazy structure composed of an ArrayList, each item of which contains an ArrayList of Objects. These Objects can be either an array of long or a String. I need to Serialize this crazy structure and am not able to achieve my goal. How about deserializing it afterwards?
I understand the basics of serialization and deserialization but am not sure about such a structure. Thank you so much for your help.

My work:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException
{   oos.defaultWriteObject();

    // Write out all elements in the proper order.
    for (Object ohs : openingHours.getAllOpeningHours())
    {
        oos.writeObject(ohs);
//            ArrayList<Object> times = (ArrayList<Object>)ohs;
//            for(Object oh:times)
//            if (oh instanceof String)
//            {
//                oos.writeChars((String) oh);
//            } else if (oh instanceof long[])
//            {
//                long[] time = (long[])oh;
//                oos.writeLong(time[0]);
//                oos.writeLong(time[1]);
//            }
    }
}
```

The "ohs" of type Object should always be ArrayList and I had found it should be already seralizable but I guess it is not that simple

Comment: Any effort yourself? If so, show it.

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Right now I am getting only EOFFile exception when reading from ObjectInputStream...

Answer (score 0):

So, as it often happens, right after posting the question I realized what was wrong. Here is the solution if anyone had a similar problem.

I have an ArrayList of objects and one of their attributes is called OpeningHours.
OpeningHours was a POJO and had one attribute that was of type ArrayList> and the Object could be either long[2] or String.
I was getting an error saying that OpeningHours is not serializable....well, it wasn't.
So I edited it a bit to the following form:
I extended the OpeningHours class with ArrayList> and since ArrayList is itself already serializable, it works with the default serialization.

```
FileOutputStream fosp = mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oosp = new ObjectOutputStream(fosp);
oosp.writeObject(mBusinessSet); //mBusiness set is ArrayList or Business. 
                                //Business contains OpeningHours attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the comments that your code is working now but here are two observation from the code snippet of your.

first is that you are using the instanceof operator with long[] data type which is a primitive one. Instance of operator cannot be used with primitive data type.

Second, try to store Long[] value in the arraylist instead of long[] as Long already implements serializable class.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your "crazy structure" into a form you feel more comfortable with. Having a list of Objects inside another list of Objects, where the second list can contain either a long[2] or a String looks like your design could need some review.

I have no idea why you need the opening hours to be represented by both a String and a long[], but I guess it would do no harm, if you move them into separate classes that implement Serializable.

Something like this:

```
public class OpeningHours implements Serializable{
private interface OpeningHour{
    public long[] getOpeningHourLongs();
    public String getOpeningHourString();
}

public static final class LongArrayOpeningHour implements OpeningHour, Serializable{
    private final long[] openingHour;

    public LongArrayOpeningHour(long[] openingHour) {
        super();
        assert openingHour.length == 2;
        this.openingHour = openingHour;
    }

    @Override
    public long[] getOpeningHourLongs() {
        return openingHour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOpeningHourString() {
        return null; // ??
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(openingHour);
    }

}
public static final class StringOpeningHour implements OpeningHour, Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8424663833219027462L;
    private final String openingHour;

    public StringOpeningHour(String openingHour) {
        super();
        this.openingHour = openingHour;
    }

    @Override
    public long[] getOpeningHourLongs() {
        return null; // ??
    }

    @Override
    public String getOpeningHourString() {
        return openingHour;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return openingHour;
    }
}

private final List<OpeningHour> openingHours;

public OpeningHours() {
    this.openingHours = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addOpeningHour(OpeningHour hour){
    this.openingHours.add(hour);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return openingHours.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OpeningHours openingHours = new OpeningHours();

    openingHours.addOpeningHour(new StringOpeningHour("I am an opening hour based on a String value"));
    openingHours.addOpeningHour(new LongArrayOpeningHour(new long[]{1,2}));

    System.out.println("openingHours before serialization: " + openingHours );

    // write OpeningHours
    OutputStream fos = null;
    String filename = ... // insert filename here
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream( filename );
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream( fos );
        o.writeObject(openingHours);
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.err.println(e); 
    } finally { 
        if (fos != null) {
            try {fos.close();} catch (IOException e1) {}
        }
    }

    // read OpeningHours
    InputStream fis = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream( filename );
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream( fis );
        openingHours = (OpeningHours) o.readObject();
        System.out.println("openingHours after deserialization: " + openingHours );
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.err.println( e ); 
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) { 
        System.err.println( e ); 
    }finally { 
        if (fis != null) {
            try {fis.close();} catch (IOException e1) {}
        }
    }
}

}
```

I believe having separate classes for these structures will certainly improve your code readability and will help you maintain and understand your code better on the long run.

Comment: yeah, it looks cool, I´ll look into it. I had something similar before and I found my solution a bit better...the structure is so crazy because the data I have to use are crazy :S